# How can I prevent the hover data from displaying in Chart.JS?

Tags: jquery, hover, tooltip, chart.js, chart.js2

I've got a horizontal bar chart that looks like this:

[image]

...but like this when I hover it:

[image]

I've tried to prevent the "hover data" from displaying like this:

```
var priceBarChart = new Chart(ctxBarChart, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    showTooltips: false,
    data: barChartData,
    options: optionsBar
});
```

...and like this:

```
var optionsBar = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [
            {
                stacked: true
            }
        ],
        yAxes: [
            {
                stacked: true
            }
        ]
    },
    showTooltips: false
};
```

...but neither works - the scrunched tip displays anyway.

How can I prevent the hover data from displaying in Chart.JS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add this to your options:

```
tooltips: {
    enabled: false
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/pen/RGojLm)

More information [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-configuration)

Answer (score 5):

Answer in 2022:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
      tooltip: {
          enabled: false
               },
           }
         },
```

[Documentation here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/configuration/tooltip.html) on Charts.js